# python requests session failed to read the response after reading a big (more than 50mb) response content

Tags: python, session

When using python requests to access some rest api, I am using request's session object. I faced a issue, when the first request is reading large content (more than 50mb) then the subsequent http request fails on the same session object. But if I didnt use the Session object then everything works fine... I have explained the code below...

```
import requests       # version 2.3.0  # python version 2.7

headers = {"Authorization":"Bearer sometoken"}

sess = requests.Session()
sess.verify = False
host = "https://somehost/endpoint/"
res = sess.get(url = host+'obj1/28/content', headers = headers)
print res  # this result received successfully with 200 response status code

url = host + 'obj2/1/content'
res = sess.get(url = url, headers=headers)  # the process running here continuously running     here. I need to kill the process to exit.
print "content ", res.content # this line never gets executed...
```

After killing the process , stack trace....

```
  File "/opt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 556, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 391, in send
    r.content
  File "/opt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 690, in content
    self._content = bytes().join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or bytes()
  File "/opt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 628, in generate
    for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):
  File "/opt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 240, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "/opt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 187, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
  File "/opt/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 567, in read
    s = self.fp.read(amt)
  File "/opt/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1313, in read
    return s + self._file.read(amt - len(s))
  File "/opt/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 380, in read
    data = self._sock.recv(left)
  File "/opt/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 242, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "/opt/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 161, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len)
```

But the same http requests with out Session object works fine.

```
print requests.get( host+'obj1/28/content', headers = headers, verify = False)
print requests.get( host+'obj2/1/content', headers = headers, verify = False)
```

Comment: Is it possible that the server doesn't handle keep-alive, or doesn't handle it properly? Requests might just be assuming that if it has an open connection in the pool it can be used no matter what, not realizing that the server will ignore the second request.

Comment: If you know nothing about the server, you can test this using `netcat`. For example, print out the HTTP requests that `requests` sends, `nc host 80`, copy and paste the request, wait for the response to finish, then copy and paste the second one and see what happens.

Comment: I don't think any issue in the server side is the cause of the issue. We have many different clients talking to Server Java/C#/PHP.. All are working fine. Also (in python) if the first requests's response is not large then all the requests are working fine with same Session..

Comment: @Shan: If the server does HTTP/1.1 but specifically refuses keep-alive, and those other clients respect that but `requests` doesn't, you'd see exactly what you're seeing. Or if it claims keep-alive but does it wrong, and those other clients aren't attempting keep-alive but `requests` is, same deal.

Answer (score 2):

From the `requests` docs:

> Excellent news — thanks to urllib3, keep-alive is 100% automatic
>   within a session! Any requests that you make within a session will
>   automatically reuse the appropriate connection!
>
> Note that **connections are only released back to the pool for reuse
>   once all body data has been read**; be sure to either set stream to
>   False or read the content property of the Response object.

Sounds like the large request is holding up that connection, or, as abarnert suggests, there's an issue with the server. Try setting `stream=False`, or access the content of that first `res` object so that `requests` knows that it can free up that connection.

EDIT: This looks like the issue. When you call `requests.get`, you set `verify = False` explicity. This is unnecessary, since the default for `requests.get` is `False`.

However, your lockup is in `adapter.send(request, **kwargs)`. So it looks like an `HTTPAdapter` object is at fault. `adapter.send` has the following signature:

```
 send(request, stream=False, timeout=None, verify=True, cert=None, proxies=None)
```

with `verify=True` as the default.

This sounds like a bug in `requests`, but my guess is that the `verify` parameter isn't getting passed down from the `Session`. The signature for `sess.request` is:

```
request(method, url, params=None, data=None, headers=None, cookies=None, files=None, auth=None, timeout=None, allow_redirects=True, proxies=None, hooks=None, stream=None, verify=None, cert=None)
```

where `verify=None` rather than `False`, so maybe that means that it's getting overriden somewhere.

Try explicitly setting `verify=False` in `sess.get`.

Comment: `stream=False` is the default, and he isn't setting `stream=True` in his code. Also, if the connection weren't released back to the pool, that means he'd get a brand-new connection, which sounds like the opposite of the problem he's having.

Comment: @abarnert I believe that `__str__()` for `res` just returns `res.status_code`, and so wouldn't be enough for `requests` to realize that it's been read from. I was unaware that `stream=False` was the default, though, hm, I'll poke through the docs more.

Comment: I tried the requests with stream=False but still same issue.

Comment: @patrick If the verify parameter isn't passed down from Session then it should not work for every case. But this issue arise only when the response of first request is large. I have also confirmed that verify parameter is passed down from Session object.

Comment: @Shan Then I'm out of ideas. The fact that you're only getting this behavior on large requests suggests a `requests` bug to me, nothing should be behaving like that. You might want to consider opening an issue up on their github.